# Firebase data in a fragment is not persistent, is re-downloaded

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager, that contains 3 Fragment

I have a TextView "Name" and ImageView "Photo" in the fragment one, when i scroll to the fragment 2 or fragment 3 and i go back to the fragment one the data is "re-donwloaded", spending more mobile data

I need that when I change the fragment, the data stays the same without needing to be downloaded again, like Facebook or Tinder

This is my code:

Fragment one:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    usr = Utils.obtainPref(getContext(), "usuario");
    mRootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_client, container, false);
    receiveData();

    return mRootView;
}
```

method receive data:

```
 private void receiveData(){

    FirebaseUtils.getUsuarioReferencia(usr).child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("username").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class) != null){
                String name = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mUsername.setText(name);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    FirebaseUtils.getUsuarioReferencia(usr).child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("description").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class) != null){
                String desc = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                mDescription.setText(desc);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    FirebaseUtils.getUsuarioReferencia(usr).child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("photoUrl").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class) != null){
                String url = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                Log.d("fotoo", url);
                StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(url);
                if(getActivity() != null){
                    storageReference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            if(getContext() != null){
                                Picasso.with(getContext()).load(uri).into(mFotoDePerfil);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The moment your listener is detached, the data is removed from memory. Keeping a listener alive while transitioning the fragments is quite non-trivial, but @DougStevenson recently wrote a series of blog posts on how to accomplish this within an activity. I recommend you read all parts ([1](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html), [2](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components_20.html), [3](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components_22.html)) and try to apply it to your situation:

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I used `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); ` and works thanks

Comment: With only disk persistence, the client will still check for new data when the new fragment is triggered. It may transfer less data than without disk persistence. The only way to guarantee no transfer is to keep the listener alive.

Answer (score 0):

override a function in the fragment setUserVisibilityHint()
and after the return statement , add this `if(getActivity()==null)
receivedata();`

dont call the receive data in the onCreateView() method or You can use a public static counter variable in a separate class and on the onCreateView() itself add this..

`if (theclass.counter==0)
receivedata();
theclass.counter++;`

Comment: Don't work, this give me a nullPointerException java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child(), when i call the database

Comment: make a separate class and a public static counter variable =0; and call it in the onCreateView() if(countervar==0)

Comment: receivedata(); counter++;

Comment: see the second part of my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new class and adding in the manifest

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
}
}
```

Manifest:

```
<application
    android:name=".app.MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```